# Cannot read property ' anynumber (0,1,2...)' of undefined

Tags: javascript, createjs

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error. I have attached screenshot of error.
[image]
Here is complete code.

```
for(var t=iStartIndex;t<aCombos.length;t++){
            if(_aFinalSymbolCombo[aCombos[t].row][aCombos[t].col] === iValue || 
                                        _aFinalSymbolCombo[aCombos[t].row][aCombos[t].col] === WILD_SYMBOL){
                iNumEqualSymbol++;

                aCellList.push({row:aCombos[t].row,col:aCombos[t].col,value:_aFinalSymbolCombo[aCombos[t].row][aCombos[t].col]});
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }

        //console.log('Value');
        //console.log('Value:'+(iNumEqualSymbol-1));
        var iV = iValue-1 ;
        var iN = iNumEqualSymbol-1 ;
        if(!isNaN(iV) && !isNaN(iN)){
        if(s_aSymbolWin[iV][iN] > 0){
            _aWinningLine.push({line:k+1,amount:s_aSymbolWin[iValue-1][iNumEqualSymbol-1], num_win:iNumEqualSymbol,value:iValue,list:aCellList});
            }
        }
```

Comment: `s_aSymbolWin[iV]` is presumably out of bounds, there is nothing at that index.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply. Here is the original code 

`if(s_aSymbolWin[iValue-1][iNumEqualSymbol-1] > 0){
                _aWinningLine.push({line:k+1,amount:s_aSymbolWin[iValue-1][iNumEqualSymbol-1], num_win:iNumEqualSymbol,value:iValue,list:aCellList});
            }`
I have tried evn to check if value  is number but it suddenly through this error.